# Is there any Python module can be adopted for [{},{}...] comparation?

Tags: python, list-comparison

It's intended to compare two lists in Python which are made up of dict elements, in each dict element, there are two keys. Below the sample is provided.

```
A=[{'id':'u2s8Et','value':'David'},{'id':'u2s0PW','value':'Linda'},......]
B=[{'id':'u2s8Et','value':'David'},{'id':'u2s7PA','value':'Steven'},......]
```

It's expected to get which elements are only available in list A and which elements in list A differ from the one in list B. Is there any existing module can be adopted to compare?

The method *assertListEqual* in **unittest** module is close to the expectation but some module more comprehensive is preferred.

Comment: You can use set operations on the lists.

Comment: You should also consider creating a class instead of using a dictionary.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice emm, it's an option to use class instead of dict as list element. Thanks.

Comment: did you leave out a word?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice would you point out which word was left out?

Comment: I am not sure if you left or a word or not. That is why I asked. Are you agreeing or not with my suggestion to create a class?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Sure, you provided a good suggestion. How can I tick your comments as best answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is that `dict`s are not hashable. Because each one of them has the same keys, though, we can convert them to a hashable type, like a `tuple`.

```
def parse(values):
    return set(map(tuple, map(dict.values, values)))

>>> parse(A)
>>> {('u2s0PW', 'Linda'), ('u2s8Et', 'David')}
```

We can now use `set` operations to compare the elements of each.

```
In [6]: parse(A).difference(parse(B))
Out[6]: {('u2s0PW', 'Linda')}

In [7]: parse(A).intersection(parse(B))
Out[7]: {('u2s8Et', 'David')}
```

`set.difference` will find the items that are in `A` but not `B`, and `set.intersection` will find the items that are in both `A` and `B`.

---

Edit: Since your `dict`s all follow the same format, you could consider using a `namedtuple`, as well.

```
In [1]: from collections import namedtuple

In [2]: entry = namedtuple("Entry", ("id", "value"))

In [3]: A = [{'id':'u2s8Et', 'value':'David'}, {'id':'u2s0PW', 'value':'Linda'}]
   ...: B = [{'id':'u2s8Et', 'value':'David'}, {'id':'u2s7PA', 'value':'Steven'}]
   ...: 

In [4]: def parse_to_entry(values):
   ...:     return {entry(d["id"], d["value"]) for d in values}
   ...: 

In [5]: parse_to_entry(A)
Out[5]: {Entry(id='u2s0PW', value='Linda'), Entry(id='u2s8Et', value='David')}

In [6]: parse_to_entry(A).difference(parse_to_entry(B))
Out[6]: {Entry(id='u2s0PW', value='Linda')}

In [7]: parse_to_entry(A).intersection(parse_to_entry(B))
Out[7]: {Entry(id='u2s8Et', value='David')}
```

Comment: Awesome! nametuple is a nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can use set operations such as `set.intersection()` and `set.difference`. Also you should consider creating a custom class instead of using dictionaries.